# Should i use less complex widgets for best flutter performance?

Tags: flutter, performance, optimization, widget

I prefer to use a Column with SizedBox to build space layout ! But my boss keep saying that i should use a Container with padding because container is less complex widget and should perform better. He always says that i should avoid stack widget because is a complex widget. But i think i remember from a  flutter video that doesn't matter which widgets you choose, because flutter optimizes it when it builds the three trees ! Is that true ?  should i spend time optimizing my widgets with less complex widgets as possible ?

```
Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
    SizedBox(height: 24),
    Text(
    text,
   ),
 ],
);
```

```
Container(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24),
     child: Text(
     text,
    ),
  );
```

In [Flutter padding desing discussion](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Padding-class.html#:%7E:text=There%20isn%27t%20really%20any,t%20implement%20its%20properties%20directly.) they said that doesn't matter if you use container with padding or specific padding widget. But i'm still in doubt if i should use less complex widget in general.

Answer (score 0):

Container is more expensive than SizedBox, Don't use container widget if SizedBox can do it for you.